# String containing code to executable function

Tags: javascript, string, function, eval

I basically want to convert a string containing code like this -

```
var code = "function Solve(args) { // do stuff and return value};";
```

into an executable function which you can pass arguments. 
   When I use it with `eval(code + "Solve(args);");` It gives me no errors but the results are not as expected. I also tried:

```
var fu = eval(code);
var result = fu(args);
```

fu stays undefined.
   Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "the results are not as expected." What do you expect to happen? What does happen? Why is that incorrect?

Comment: The arguments are passed correctly but the result from the function is wrong.

Comment: Then maybe posting the actual body of the function rather than `// do stuff and return value` might be helpful?

Answer (score 3):

Using eval is normally a very bad way of doing things.

eval is going to put the code into the Global namespace

```
var code = "function Solve(args) { return args * 2}";  
eval(code); 
var val = 1;
var result = Solve(val);
```

if you do not know the name, you would have to do something like this

```
var code = "function Solve2(args) { return args * 2}";
var val = 3;  
var result = eval("(" + code + ")(" + val + ");");
```

problem with the above method is it will use toString()

A better way to make a function from a string is using [new Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

```
var sumCode = "return a + b";
var sum = new Function("a","b", sumCode);
sum(1,2);
```

Comment: Thank you. I found my mistake. I think this approuch is the best because if you want to reuse the function with different args you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

this works on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzwYv/):

```
var code = "function Solve(args) { alert(args)};"; 
eval(code + "Solve('test');");
```

what is the function and result you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
eval(code + "fu = Solve(args);");

console.log(fu);
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers proposed using eval, so here is a mildly different approach.

Try this and tell me how you like it:

```
var code = "alert('I am an alert')";
var codeToFunction = new Function(code);
codeToFunction();
```